# Node.js - Mongoose UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: queryTxt

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to connect my Node.js app to Mongodb Atlas. This is the code I use:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const _ = require("lodash");

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://admin-name:******@cluster0.tlksq.mongodb.net/fruitsDB", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

I have tryed everything I know using the connect to cluster in Atlas but I keep getting this error:

```
(node:11660) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0.tlksq.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:206:19)
(node:11660) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11660) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I don't know if it is related to the catch block they say but, is it feasible using mongoose? if it is possible, how do I use it? Thank you so much!

Comment: The error is occurring due to the fact that mongoose.connect() is executing a promise internally which is throwing an error due to Connection Timeout. Check your credentials and try to connect to the database from other application (Studio3T or cmd). ETimeout occurs due to invalid credentials or if the database is not reachable.

Comment: I was able to connect using the Mongo Shell method, but I keep having these issues:
- The connection shows SECONDARY, so I can't use commands like show dbs
- It only connects to admin database, but if I try other database or to create a new one I can't. Like using mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0.tlksq.mongodb.net/newDB" --username admin-name

I also checked the password and IP whitelisting.